# How can we access SQL Server data over the internet ? Right now I can access the server in local area network

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, database-connection

I have VB.NET code that works perfectly with SQL Server 2008 R2, over local area network on multiple computers. Now I am looking for solution, where computers are in different parts of the country and need to access the same database over the internet.

In local area network, it is very easy, since I can access the laptop having the server and services running on it. But how to do the same over the internet?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into a server client approach and a suitable framework for that. You normally dont expose a SQL server to internet or even DMZ

Comment: Can you guide me, where should I get knowledge for above?  Any favorite article or video you can suggest? I tried to Google, I hardly know what I am looking for. So i get all lost in that.

Comment: In my experience this is something you do under guidance of an experienced architect the first couple of years of working professionally with it.
But sure, as proposed below, if it should remain on a hobbyist level you can connect the locations with vpn.
This is managed by the infrastructure team/provider/partner.

Answer (score 0):

This topic is far larger than a Stack Overflow answer can be. You do not want to expose a SQL Server to the internet at large, it will become a target of malicious attacks almost immediately.

You need a VPN to connect your office locations, essentially putting them all on the "same" network but protected with firewalls and encryption. This is a job for network and security engineers, you can't just pick up a box at the local big box electronics store and be done.

SQL Server 2008 R2 was declared End of Life by Microsoft on July 9th. You needed to upgrade two months ago. There will be no fixes, no patches, no support for it ever again, unless you're prepared to pay 7+ figures (US Dollars). Exposing *that* to the internet? No way.

Further, you say you can "access the laptop having the server and service on it." Laptops are not server-grade hardware! They are (relatively speaking) slow, and very prone to failing, getting damaged, stolen, unplugged, and worse. If you are running a server, *buy a server*. Or better yet, go to the cloud.

Your best move here is to contract with a service provider or consulting firm to get you through this whole process. From your description, attempting to make this work is going to result in a failure of your system at best, and compromise of your data, systems, and possible catastrophic results for your whole organization.

Answer (score 0):

Easy:

As @alroc said SQL Server 2008 R2 was declared End of Life by Microsoft on July 9th.
So you don't have much choice: upload your database to Azure.

[image]

This way your database will be upgraded to a latest version and it will be accessible all over the World following the latest security standard.

Keep in mind that by consequence you might also need to upgrade some part of your VB.NET code. But i cannot grantee you that because you haven't posted any code.